# Trouble with return in python

Tags: python

```
####
# GCD calculator using euclidean algorithm
####

def euclid_gcd(x,y) :
    new_gcd = y
    remainder = x % y
    print x,y, new_gcd, remainder
    if(remainder != 0) :
        euclid_gcd(y,remainder)   
    else :
        print x,y, new_gcd, remainder
        return new_gcd

print 'x | y | new_gcd | remainder'
print euclid_gcd(252,198)
```

However, when I run this code it returns this...

```
x | y | new_gcd | remainder
252 198 198 54
198 54 54 36
54 36 36 18
36 18 18 0
36 18 18 0
None
```

It should return 18 in this case yet it returns none where did I go wrong everything seems to be following the logical steps??

Answer (score 4):

You should do `return euclid_gcd(y,remainder)`.

You forgot to return the recursion result here:

```
if(remainder != 0) :
    euclid_gcd(y,remainder)
```

Comment: Oh yea? where should I place that please?

Comment: Oh wow that fixed it! could I bother you for one more second and ask why that fixed it?

Comment: @cat:  Most compiled languages wouldn't let you get away (as in won't compile) with returning something in one part, but not another.  The same thing applies here - you have to return the value you get back from the method call, or it won't give you back an answer.

Comment: @cat, I believe Makoto has described this better than I can :)

Comment: Brilliant I can't believe I didn't notice that thank you guys!

Answer (score 1):

Another way to solve your problem

```
def euclid_gcd(x, y):
    new_gcd = y
    remainder = x % y
    print x, y, new_gcd, remainder
    if remainder != 0:
        new_gcd = euclid_gcd(y, remainder)   
    print x, y, new_gcd, remainder
    return new_gcd
```

I suggested this because it seems strange otherwise to have the variable `new_gcd` if you only ever initialise it to `y`

The reason that you were getting `None` is because Python implicitly returns `None` if the function doesn't explicitly return anything